# Tables ignore given format

Tags: php, css, phpword

I'm trying to add some tables to a document, which after lot of work, it's showing right. Generated with PHPWord. The issue is that whatever I add in the table,row or cell style, it doesn't modify the table.

I've already tried: `$table->addRow(15)`, `$table->addRow(array('height'=>15))` and as is shown in the code below.

Also, there is no documentation on how to add a cell with two lines of text, because below 'Sign' I have to add 'Name'.

```
//TABLE1
$table = $section->addTable(array('width'=>100, 'borderSize'=> 1, 'borderColor'=>'000000'));
$table->addRow(15,array('height'=>15));
$table->addCell(array('width'=>150))->addText('COMPANY', $smallBoldFont);
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell()->addText('');
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell()->addText('');
//TABLE1
$section->addTextBreak(2);
//TABLE2
$table2 = $section->addTable(array('borderSize'=> 1, 'borderColor'=>'000000'));
$table2->addRow(100,array('height'=>80));
$table2->addCell(150,array('width'=>800))->addText('Recibed', $smallFont8);
$table2->addRow();
$table2->addCell()->addText('Time:', $smallFont8);
$table2->addCell()->addText('Sign:', $smallFont8);
//TABLE2
```

Is there a reason why PHPWord ignores my format style to tables? Is there any other way of doing it better?

Desired output:

[image]

Actual output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation is all. Just to read it deeply. Here is section how to create [tables](http://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/elements.html#tables), including creation of tables with multicolumn cells

I don't know if PHPWord has some pre-defined units for case if you miss to use them. But it seems you need to set units for width. But you should test units and numbers as you need.

Order to create multicolumn cell is gridSpan(). So line for creation of the first row of the second table (probably) should be:

```
$table2->addCell(150,array('width'=>800))->gridSpan(2) ->addText('Recibed', $smallFont8);
```

PHPWord uses twip as default unit. And all cells have to match its width.
The smallest cell is taken for entire column.

For convertion from twips to other units may be used [EndMemo (Topography Conversion Online)](http://endmemo.com/convert/topography.php).

250 pixels are 3750 twips.

Comment: I used all formats like shown in that doc.

Adding units doesn't work, just tried that.

The last part of your answer worked perfectly, so thanks for that.

Comment: PHPWord seems very interesting - but I rather stay on using of my own way (my own HTML code generator), even if it is not perfect.

Comment: Seems that units are in twips, and all cells have to match its width. The smallest cell width is taken for an entire column. Here is a twip to other units converter http://endmemo.com/convert/topography.php, like 3750 twips are 250 px. Add this to your answer please, and I'll accept it. So other could find this info eassier.

Comment: Added that what you wished I add to my answer. I hope that correctly.